# How to connect with Wifi Camera ios

Tags: ios, camera, wifi, ip-address, connect

I need some help, in my project i need to get images captured by **wifi camera**. I need to connect with that camera with **IPAddress** and get those images. I am completely new to this topic, so please suggest me that 
**1) How to connect with wifi cameras using IPAddress** 
**2) How to get captured pictures automatically**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hello. Have you find any solution how to connect to WIFI Camera? I am facing the same issue please share the solution. Which SDK did you use for connecting the Wifi Camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `iOS` you can't connect the `WIFI` network from your application. Apple has not grant permission to access the `WIFI` setting inside the other app. You only get the name of connected `WIFI` inside your application. So search like `SSID` in ios for wifi. After that check that this `SSID` is the correct one means it is that camera `WIFI`. IF not then display message to user and tell them to goto the `Setting` app and select your camera `WIFI`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello Nirav D. Have you worked on how to connect to WIFI Camera? I am facing the same issue please share the solution if any. Which SDK did you use for connecting the Wifi Camera if you have done?