# How can I connect with my previous Wifi Network through coding in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, application-settings

My scenario is like this.

I have a `UIWebView` which contains a `HTML` page. In that `HTML` page I have 5 screen. When user click on next button (on webpage, not native button) then It will show second screen of `HTML` page.

Like that on 3rd screen I am connected with CCTV camera hotspot through Phone setting page. When I came back to app from phone setting page and I don't want to process the instillation of CCTV, then I want to exist that webView `ViewController`. That time my app is already in camera hotspot network.

I want to connect with my home previous wifi network and disconnect the camera hotspot network. Means switch between previous and current network.

I googled, but all told its not possible in iOS. Apple will reject the app.

Can anybody give me the solution, How can I resolve this issue. ?

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37937688/6433023)