# How to fetch all WiFi connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi

Please solve my problem, If anybody know about to find all nearby WiFi connection. Actually i want to connectivity iPhone to android and iPhone to iPhone vice versa for sending text.

Comment: You can not get list of wifi or could not select any one from the app. Read this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937514/how-to-connect-with-wifi-camera-ios/37937688#37937688) for more about this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you can refer.

```
- (NSDictionary *)fetchSSIDInfo
{

NSArray *interfaceNames = CFBridgingRelease(CNCopySupportedInterfaces());
NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, interfaceNames);

NSDictionary *SSIDInfo;
for (NSString *interfaceName in interfaceNames) {
    SSIDInfo = CFBridgingRelease(
        CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)interfaceName));
    NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, interfaceName, SSIDInfo);

    BOOL isNotEmpty = (SSIDInfo.count > 0);
    if (isNotEmpty) {
        break;
    }
}
return SSIDInfo;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for giving me a suggestion. Shubham It's only shows my network connection not the all WiFi connections. I want to know, without connect with internet connection how to detect nearby WiFi networks name.

Comment: It gives an exception on line number 61  **apple80211Open(&airportHandle)**  EXC_Bad_ACCESSS